# MS Excel Reordering letters in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of cells containing content in the format `ABCDP2S6_EFGHP2Te6_X_YY.Y_ZZZ`

I want to use a formula command to output `CDABP2S6-GHEFP2Te6`

I googled and it seems to involve REPLACE and FIND, but can't figure out a right way to do it.

Any help?

Comment: Is that hyphen in the desired output a typo? Or the underscore in the input? What about the order of letters? What are your conditions here? Is the input always the same length? Do you always want to shuffle the same letters? There is too little information here right now.

Comment: The hyphen and underscore are not typos. I need to replace the underscore with a hyphen. I need to replace ABCD to CDAB and EFGH to GHEF, then the underscore to hyphen. The length is always the same and I want to shuffle the same letters every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try, assuming the same length for each value in your input  as per your comments:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=CONCAT(MID("-"&A1,{4,2,6,1,13,11,15},{2,2,4,1,2,2,5}))
```

Here I simply use arrays of integers to grab substrings of length 1, 2, 4 or 5 characters. To avoid a somewhat lengthy formula and double use of `MID()` the first step was to add a leading hyphen to the input which we can reference in the indexes too. This would simply shift all other characters to the right by one; thus their respective position in the input will also change.

As per [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mid-function-2eba57be-0c05-4bdc-bf81-5ecf4421eb8a) the 2nd parameter should tell the function a starting position whereas the 3rd parameter will tell the function the lenght of the substring to take from the given start position. Hence you can look at the two arrays of pairs of elements. So each index within the 1st array has a counterpart at the same index in the 2nd array:

[image]

---

If this does not paint a clear picture, just skip the part where we use a leading hyphen and use the original input like so:

```
=CONCAT(MID(A1,{3,1,5},{2,2,4}),"-",MID(A1,{12,10,14},{2,2,5}))
```

If even this is not straightforward enough, then write out each individual starting position and extract a single character each time:

```
=CONCAT(MID(A1,{3,4,1,2,5,6,7,8},1),"-",MID(A1,{12,13,10,11,14,15,16,17,18},1))
```

---

A reasonable alternative could be to `TEXTPLIT()` the input first, then apply the same tricks, but this time with a trailing hyphen:

```
=CONCAT(MID(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"_"),2)&"-",{3,1,5},{2,2,5}))
```

Comment: Thanks JvdV, can you roughly explain the syntax?

Comment: The new version seems to miss the 6 of the Te6

Comment: The old version of the solution is very straighforward, but I have trouble understanding the syntax of the simplified version. Can you elaborate your syntax a bit more than what you have included in the solution now? Like what each variable in the {4,2,6,1,13,11,15}, and {2,2,4,1,2,2,5} mean? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jacek Put these 3 arrays in 3 columns: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19}`, `{-,A,B,C,D,P,2,S,6,_,E,F,G,H,P,2,T,e,6}`, `{9,3,4,1,2,5,6,7,8,,12,13,10,11,14,15,16,17,18}`. Now start with number 1 in the 3rd column. Look in the first column and it's number 4 for the 1st resulting array and number 2 for the 2nd resulting array i.e. 1 and 2 are only consecutive. Now go to 3 in the 3rd column and in column 1 you will find 2 which is the 2nd number for the 1st resulting array and 2 again for the 2nd resulting array because only 3 and 4 are consecutive. Now go to 5 in the 3rd...

Comment: At first glance, I thought *"what?"*. But then I started dissecting it and it all fell into place. Thanks for this lesson. BTW, in which program did you make this image?

Comment: @VBasic2008, just some Excel shapes to be honest.

Comment: Since @JvdV Sir has already given so many beautiful alternatives hence not adding in answers, just adding in comments, with one more way using `TEXTJOIN()` : `=TEXTJOIN({"","","-","","",""},,MID(A1,{3,1,5,12,10,14},{2,2,4,2,2,5}))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `TEXTBEFORE()` function.

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1,"_X")
```

For older versions, use-

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("_X",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Also take a look at letters order - ABCD to CDAB, EFGH to GHEF

Comment: @user11222393 Good point. OP need to clarify those.

Comment: The main point here is to switch ABCD to CDAB and EFGH to GHEF

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that defines a user `LAMBDA` function, which could be extended for a more general case (see below):

```
=LET(A,A1, split,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A,"_"),,2),
 REVERSE2, LAMBDA(x, CONCAT(SORTBY(MID(x,{1,3},{2,2}),{2,1}))),
 TEXTJOIN("-",, BYCOL(split, LAMBDA(x,REVERSE2(LEFT(x,4)) & RIGHT(x,LEN(x)-4)))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

First, we split via `TEXTSPLIT` and take only the first two columns (`split`). We define a user `LAMBDA` function, which reverses the order for a string of `4` characters taking groups of `2` characters, i.e. `REVERSE2("ABCD")` returns `"CDAB"`. We iterate (`x`) over all columns of `split` via `BYCOL` to apply `REVERS2` for the first `4` characters, then concatenate the result with the remaining portion of the string. Finally, concatenate the entire result via `TEXTJOIN` with `-` as a delimiter.

`REVERSE2` function can be extended to a more general case: For a string (`x`) of length `h`, to split into groups of substrings of length `m`, and reverse the order in groups of size `k`. Where `h` should be divisible by `m` and by `m*k`:

```
REVERSEBYMK=LAMBDA(x,m,k,LET(n,LEN(x)/m, s,SEQUENCE(n,,0), start,SEQUENCE(n,,,m),
 size,m*(s+1)^0, CONCAT(SORTBY(MID(x,start,size),k-MOD(s,k)+k*INT(s/k)))))
```

For example:

| String | m | k | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 2 | 2 | CDAB |
| ABCD1234 | 4 | 2 | 1234ABCD |
| ABCD1234 | 2 | 2 | CDAB3412 |
| 123456789ABCDEFGHI | 3 | 3 | 789456123GHIDEFABC |
| 1234567890ABCDEFGHIJ | 2 | 2 | 34127856AB90EFCDIJGH |
| AB | 1 | 2 | BA |